# Is the syntax of this IF/OR statement wrong?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What is wrong with this code?

```
var variable = prompt("Choose answer1, answer2, answer3 or answer4");
if ((variable !== "answer1") || (variable !== "answer2") || (variable !== "answer3") || (variable !== "answer4")) {
    return "You must choose one of these four options!"
}
```

Comment: Should be != right?

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_syntax.asp

Comment: @JeffLee First of all, please **never** use w3schools *ever again*, and secondly, `!==` is a perfectly valid JavaScript operator.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: You need to use **and** instead of **or**.  Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: The condition is always true.

Comment: @serakfalcon I wanna return the sentence if the user write a answer different of those options I've asked him to choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution will be always true because variable will not allways be all answers at the same time.

You could use == instead of !== and then negate the whole expression:

```
if (!((variable == "answer1") || (variable == "answer2") || (variable == "answer3") || (variable == "answer4"))) {
```

or use and instead of or

```
if ((variable !== "answer1") && (variable !== "answer2") && (variable !== "answer3") && (variable !== "answer4")) {
```

in both cases the expression will be true if it is not any of the answers and false if it is one answer.

Comment: Wouldn't your `and` example always produce a `false`?

Comment: I tried this but it wasn't successful... even with equal value or type operator (I don't know if is right to use)...

Comment: Lets see for variable not beeing an answer all 4 would be true therefore it would true. If variable == "answer1" the variable !== "answer1" would be false an therefore the whole thing would be  would be false

Comment: which of the two have you tried? because the both work see also @Pete seeing is believing ^^ http://jsfiddle.net/d8pzacs2/1/

Comment: Vielen Dank! With your tip I realized I was using a return out of a function... how foolish I'm! haha

Comment: Then welcome to stackexchange @Zucareli and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @trudbert You're correct.  My interpretation of what he wanted as incorrect.

Comment: @Pete you made me stare a it for a minute trying to find what I was missing ^^ (It was 4:50 in the morning here and about 10 minutes before coffee...)